# What do you call a male child of your female cousin?

Tags: kinship-terms

OK, a nephew is a male child of your siblings.

But what do you call a male child of your female cousin?

1. A cousin nephew?
2. A nephew cousin?
3. ...?

Comment: The marked duplicate has an answer that explains this.

Comment: Why do you think that sex matters here?

Answer (score 3):

That would be your **first cousin once removed**.

The term is the same whatever the gender of your cousin or the child.

https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/Understanding-Kinship-Terms

> In cousin relationships, the term removed indicates the separation of a generation. Your first cousin is the same generation as you are, so your first cousin once removed would be either your parent’s first cousin or your first cousin’s child.